# How to pass a macro(which has args) by a key made from \pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following example, I tried four methods to pass those macros who have args by a key made from `\pgfkeys`. And all of them do not work.

What shall I do?

CODE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{
  % a/.code=#1,
  a/.ecode=\noexpand#1,
  % a/.expand once=\noexpand#1,
  %a/.initial=#1,
}
\pgfkeys{a=\color}{red} some red-colored text\par
\pgfkeys{a=\makebox}[s]{1in} {some text in a box}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Both of your usage examples have the arguments outside of the `\pgfkeys` input: did  you mean to try for example `\pgfkeys{a=\color{red}}`?

Comment: No, I want to only pass macro itself .

Comment: That would make the answer 'you can't do this': even with one key, `\pgfkeys` (or similar) does not produce `\color{red}` but `\color<stuff for pgfkeys>{red}`. However, I think what's needed here is an idea of _why_ you are trying to do that.

Comment: I learned how to store value or macro without args(\centering etc.) in a key by `\pgfkeys`, but I don't know how to store a macro with args(like \color, \parbox) in a key and then activate it. This is why I pose this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to store `\color` inside a macro such that you can re-insert the tokens later. I'd therefore go for

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{a/.store in = \mycolorfn}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{a=\color}\mycolorfn{red} some red-colored text\par
\end{document}
```

You can't rely on what comes at the end of key setting: there are a lot of tokens inserted by `\pgfkeys` (the same is true for other keyval processors, in general).

Comment: Thank you @Joseph Wright! In this solution, another macro `mycolorfn` has to be introduced. I wonder if there is a method without using a new macro.